# Are the docs for Struts 1 still available online?

Tags: documentation, struts, struts-1

I have needed to maintain a Struts 1 application. I know, EOL almost two years ago, no new releases in six years. Whatever, we have 100k lines of working code in a Struts 1 app, and it's not going away just because I have more modern sensibilities.

I've looked for the docs, so I can understand this ancient framework, and I'm coming up empty. [This link](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/userGuide/index.html) is broken. [This site](http://struts.apache.org) seems to only have Struts 2 information, if you don't count the EOL announcement.

Does anyone know of a site where the old docs are hosted? I'll be extra grateful if someone can point to docs for Struts 1.2.7.

Comment: http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/documentation/.

Comment: Sad that this question gets an upvote today (5 years after EOL, almost 10 years after last release.)

Comment: @EricWilson: The [last snapshot of the Struts 1.3.10 documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130104113217/http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/userGuide/index.html) can be found on archive.org, as can be [for Struts 1.2.7](https://web.archive.org/web/20121104185635/http://struts.apache.org:80/1.2.7/userGuide/index.html). In contrast to their EOL statement, Apache seem to have removed everything somewhere between Febrary and March 2013. As for "sadness" - well, re-read your opening sentences. For some of us, this still hasn't changed...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Accoring to [this article](https://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html), the docs **should** be:

With the announcement of Struts 1 EOL, what happens to Struts 1 resources?

> All resources will stay where they are. The documentation will still
>   be accessible from the Apache Struts homepage, as well as the
>   downloads for all released Struts 1.x versions. All of the Struts 1
>   source code can be found in the Apache Struts subversion repository,
>   now and in future. All released Maven artifacts will still be
>   accessible in Maven Central.

---

This
[LINK](http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/documentation/) shows the archived docs in zip format.

[image]

Would be the file path.

Comment: It seems not quite true, I can't actually browse/search any docs that I have found at the web page other than struts2 docs.

Comment: @EricWilson: try opening them in a new tab - it seems to 'like' that. (i've just d/l'd the struts-1.3.10-docs.zip)

Comment: Didn't work for me on my Mac. Command click started a download.

Comment: extract the downloaded file, and open the docs folder, and open any of the html documents contained. (it's not an online doc, it's hosted locally on your machine)

Comment: I'll accept this if nothing better comes, I'm just hoping that I can find something that I can google. Locally hosted docs are more limited.

Comment: [closest web](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Struts) doc I could find i'm afraid.

Comment: @EricWilson: *that I can google. Locally hosted docs are more limited* - in which way there are more limited? You can search local files better than gooooogling around.

Comment: @AleksandrM Of course, I can restrict my google search to a particular site, and you may find that the results are better than what you get with `ack` or `grep`. Sometimes you don't know the exact terms that you need.

Answer (score 11):

The answer from @jbutler483 is correct, but unfortunately is not enough to find the documentation for Struts 1.2.7, because there are only documentation for Struts 1.3.5+ in the [documentation repo](http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/struts-1.2.7/).

However, inside [the full Struts 1.2.7 zip](http://archive.apache.org/dist/struts/struts-1.2.7/), there is a file named **struts-documentation.war**, which have the full documentation.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @jbutler483 and @Arturo's answers, I found this on the apache SVN repo for Struts 1.1

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts1/tags/STRUTS_1_2_9/legacy/api-1.1/index.html

There also is xdocs for 1.2.9 here:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/struts/struts1/tags/STRUTS_1_2_9/xdocs/

This online link comes in handy if your organization makes a stink out of downloading binaries from the internet (mine does).

P.S Don't mean to open an old thread, but I was looking for this today and thought it might help someone.

Comment: Slightly OT: I'm quite amazed I've never come across the XDoc format. If anybody else is interested aswell, [here's some info](https://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/xdoc-format.html).

Comment: Great discovery! That way I can configure it in my IDE without having to deploy the doc war.